# Does Mirror's Edge run on Windows 7 Home Professional 64-Bit?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, mirrors-edge

I was considering buying Mirror's Edge from Direct2Drive when it was on sale, but then noticed this at the bottom of the page:

> **Known Issues**
>   Windows 7 is not supported

Has anyone had any trouble running Mirror's Edge on Windows 7 Home Professional 64-bit? If so, what steps did you take to resolve the issue? I don't want to buy the game if it won't run on my machine.

Comment: Bear in mind that *not supported* is more of a [CYA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass) thing, and does not necessarily mean *won't run*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i remember i played it on Windows 7 64 bits without any problem. Strange notice. However google and some boards are saying it's physX related and ATI for the ones having issues running it.

Comment: Likewise, though my copy came from Steam (no idea why there would be a difference).  I do have an Nvidia card, FWIW.

Comment: My situation is the same as Nick T, and it runs perfectly for me. Fun game.

Comment: I've ran it on windows 7 and I have an ATI card with no problems.  I did remember that I had to do something with physx though, but its been a while and I forgot what.  Google should solve that for you.

Comment: I was having an immediate crash without logo on Windows 8.1 with a 2013 NVidia card. Fixed by copying "Mirror's Edge\Binaries\PhysXLocal\PhysXLoader.dll" to "Mirror's Edge\Binaries\PhysXLoader.dll" per this thread (http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2127437)